# How to make HTML "data-" attributes show up in form POST?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a work scheduling app that assigns workers to shifts.  One thing the user can do is trade two workers between two shifts.  This is done with a "select" control.  So far I have been identifying the shifts and workers by packing their ids to the "value" field of each "option", like this:

```
<option 
    value="
        action:trade 
        this_shift:439 
        this_worker:32 
        that_shift:436 
        that_worker:10"
>
    Thu 2019-07-04 for Carl Ross
</option>
```

This works OK, but my PHP and JS code both have to spend a lot of time extracting those data out of the "value" string.

I recently discovered the HTML5 feature that enables adding custom data attributes to HTML input fields by prefixing each custom attribute name with "data-".  So now I'm trying to represent the various identifiers with explicit custom attributes in the "option" definition, like this:

```
<option 
    data-action="trade" 
    data-thisShift="439" 
    data-thisWorker="32" 
    data-thatShift="436" 
    data-thatWorker="10"
>
    Thu 2019-07-04 for Carl Ross
</option>
```

This works fine for picking up the data with Javascript.  But when the form is submitted, the "data-" attributes don't show up as elements in the POST request.  Is there anyway to get the "data-" attributes into the POST?

Comment: How are you submitting this...default form process or ajax?

Comment: Default form submit process.

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as the right answer? Or what else do you want to see? I could add some more things about the data-* attributes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid, you have to write some kind of a script to manually gather those custom data and create hidden form fields from them which then get sent. You could do that on submit by a onsubmit handler for example.

Comment: data-* attributes do not have a visual representation and they do not effect the form data. They are there to store information in them and they can be manipulated by Javascript or access them through CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a default form submit you could get the `dataset` from the selected option and create a hidden input for each attribute to append to the form

```js
document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  // remove from production -- demo only
  evt.preventDefault();  
  
  const form = this,
    sel = form.mySelect,
    optData = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].dataset;
    
  //TODO:  validate optData before proceeding
  
  // iterate optData and create hidden input for each key/value pair
  Object.entries(optData).forEach(function(entry) {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'hidden';
    input.name = entry[0];
    input.value = entry[1];
    form.appendChild(input);
  })
  // see the new elements in demo
  console.log(form.innerHTML)

})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">

  <select id="mySelect">
    <option data-action="trade" data-thisShift="439" data-thisWorker="32" data-thatShift="436" data-thatWorker="10" selected>
      Thu 2019-07-04 for Carl Ross
    </option>
  </select>

  <button>Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Something like this, yes!

Answer (score 0):

Why you u are creating a dynamic input element if not required. just create a hidden input field and on form Submission pass value form Jquery. just simple. no need of write more lines for code that makes you code poor...

```
$("#MyForm").on("submit",function(e){
e.preventDefault();  
$("#hiddenField").val($("#YourSource").val()) 
});
```